# preg_replace to preg_replace_callback with an array as replacement

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I'm migrating an application to work with **PHP 5.5**, and I need to remove the /e character from the preg_replace function, to do that I'm using preg_replace_callback()

My actual function looks like this:

```
preg_replace ( '#\{([a-z0-9\-_]*?)\}#Ssie' , '( ( isset($array[\'\1\']) ) ? $array[\'\1\'] : \'\' );' , $template );
```

Where:

**$template** contains a html document with tags like this one: **{user_name}**

and **$array** contains

```
$array['user_name'] = 'The user';
```

I've been trying to convert this to work with PHP 5.5 with not success.

This is what I did so far:

```
return preg_replace_callback ( '#\{([a-z0-9\-_]*?)\}#Ssi' , function ( $array ) {
    return ( ( isset ( $array[1] ) ) ? $array[1] : '' );
} , $template );
```

But It's not working. **The tags closed in braces are not being replaced**.

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `use` keyword to pull in `$array` into your anonymous function...

```
return preg_replace_callback ( '#\{([a-z0-9\-_]*?)\}#Ssi' , function ($matches) use ($array) {
    return ( ( isset ( $array[$matches[1]] ) ) ? $array[$matches[1]] : '' );
} , $template );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect! I'd tried with use but I miss this: $array[$matches[1]]

Comment: @fire How would you do this using a single array, passing array_keys($preg) as the Search param, and array_values($preg) as the callback array? This causes an error: `$body = preg_replace_callback (array_keys($preg), function ($matches) use (array_values($preg)) { return ((isset($array[$matches[1]])) ? $array[$matches[1]] : ''); },$body);` Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b18934bfcf758e128915a1a5d5e9fa97d17411ab